# Observer Pattern not working

Tags: c++, observer-pattern

so I have this problem I've been practicing with for my OOP exam and I've tried building an observer design pattern. 
Unfortunately, it seems that every time I initialise an interface, it somehow makes a copy of my controller and that means a new copy of the list of observers. Thus, my interfaces not being updated.

My observer:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
class Observer
{
public:
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual ~Observer() {}
};

class Observable
{
private:
    std::vector<Observer*> observers;

public:

    virtual ~Observable() {}
    void addObserver(Observer *obs)
    {
        observers.push_back(obs);
    }
    void removeObserver(Observer *obs)
    {
        observers.erase(std::remove(observers.begin(), observers.end(), obs));
    }
    void notify()
    {
        for (auto obs : observers)
        {
            obs->update();
        }
    }
};
```

This is the interface that needs to be updated:

```
class Practice : public QWidget, public Observer
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Practice(Controller& ctrl, Teacher& t, QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

--------------
Practice::Practice(Controller& ctrl, Teacher& t, QWidget *parent) : ctrl{ ctrl }, t{ t }, QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(ui.studentList, &QListWidget::itemSelectionChanged, this, [this]() {this->listItemChanged(); });
    QObject::connect(ui.gradeButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Practice::on_gradeButton_clicked);
    this->populateStudentsList();
    this->ctrl.addObserver(this);
}
```

My main: (I open as many windows as there are "teachers")

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Repository repo("Student.txt", "Teacher.txt");
    Controller ctrl(repo);
    std::vector<Teacher> temp = ctrl.getRepo().getTeachers();
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); ++i)
    {
        Practice* p = new Practice{ctrl, temp[i]};
        p->setWindowTitle(QString::fromStdString(temp[i].getName()));
        p->show();
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Also, my controller inherits from Observable.

I debugged it and I came to the conclusion that a new controller is created every time I initialise a "Practice" and I don't know why.

Thank you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173189/discussion-on-question-by-bryuki-hk-observer-pattern-not-working).

Answer (score 1):

> I debugged it and I came to the conclusion that a new controller is created every time I initialise a "Practice" and I don't know why.

You did not show the *full* declaration of your `Practice` class, but it is clear from your constructor definition that there is a `ctrl` member present in the class.

If that `ctrl` member is NOT declared as a reference (`Controller&`), then when the constructor calls `ctrl{ ctrl }` in the member initialization list, a *copy* of the input `ctrl` object is made, even though the input `ctrl` object is being passed to the constructor by reference.

If the `Controller` object is meant to outlive the `Practice` objects (which seems to be the case), then consider making the `Practice::ctrl` member be a reference/pointer to the input `Controller` object, not a *copy* of it:

```
class Practice : public QWidget, public Observer
{
    ...
private:
    Controller &ctrl;
    ...
public:
    Practice(Controller& ctrl, ...);
    ~Practice();
    ...
};

Practice::Practice(Controller& ctrl, ...) : ctrl{ ctrl }, ...
{
    ...
    this->ctrl.addObserver(this);
}

Practice::~Practice()
{
    ...
    this->ctrl.removeObserver(this);
}
```

Or:

```
class Practice : public QWidget, public Observer
{
    ...
private:
    Controller *ctrl;
    ...
public:
    Practice(Controller& ctrl, ...);
    ~Practice();
    ...
};

Practice::Practice(Controller& ctrl, ...) : ctrl{ &ctrl }, ...
{
    ...
    this->ctrl->addObserver(this);
}

Practice::~Practice()
{
    ...
    this->ctrl->removeObserver(this);
}
```

Alternatively, consider wrapping the `Controller` object inside of a `std::shared_ptr<Controller>`, and then declare the `Practice::ctrl` member as `std::shared_ptr<Controller>` to match.

```
class Practice : public QWidget, public Observer
{
    ...
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Controller> ctrl;
    ...
public:
    Practice(std::shared_ptr<Controller> ctrl, ...);
    ...
};

Practice::Practice(std::shared_ptr<Controller> ctrl, ...) : ctrl{ ctrl }, ...
{
    ...
    this->ctrl->addObserver(this);
}

Practice::~Practice()
{
    ...
    this->ctrl->removeObserver(this);
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Controller> ctrl = std::make_shared<Controller>(repo);
    ...
    Practice* p = new Practice{ctrl, temp[i]};
    ...
}
```

Either way, multiple `Practice` objects will be able to share a single `Controller` object.

Answer (score 0):

thank you, but apparently I forgot to reference the controller in the definition of the class... my bad. Thank you to all and have a good day!